Graph coloring optimization with quantum computing
I'm a computer science student at the University of Geneva, currently working on my bachelor thesis. My project involves conducting a significant optimization task on graph coloring using quantum computing. I'm seeking advice on where to start and which algorithms to consider.
I require an algorithm capable of efficiently handling a large number of nodes, as my graph is quite substantial. While I'm already utilizing the IBM Quantum Lab, I'm uncertain if it can accommodate such a large-scale task.
Thank you for taking the time to read this post and for any assistance you can provide!
Take care, Leo

Grover's algorithm and quantum walks immediately come to mind. Grovers works in $O(\sqrt{2^n})$, where $n$ is the number of nodes.
